# Split function difference between char and string arguments

Tags: scala, split

I try the following code in scala REPL:

```
"ASD-ASD.KZ".split('.')
res7: Array[String] = Array(ASD-ASD, KZ)

"ASD-ASD.KZ".split(".")
res8: Array[String] = Array()
```

Why this function calls have a different results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a big difference in the function use.

The `split` function is overloaded, and this is the implementation from the source code of Scala:

> /** For every line in this string:
>
> - Strip a leading prefix consisting of blanks or control characters
> - followed by `|` from the line.
>
> */

```
  def stripMargin: String = stripMargin('|')

  private def escape(ch: Char): String = "\\Q" + ch + "\\E"

  @throws(classOf[java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException])
  def split(separator: Char): Array[String] = toString.split(escape(separator))

  @throws(classOf[java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException])
  def split(separators: Array[Char]): Array[String] = {
    val re = separators.foldLeft("[")(_+escape(_)) + "]"
    toString.split(re)
  }
```

So when you're calling `split()` with a char, you ask to split by that specific char:

```
scala> "ASD-ASD.KZ".split('.')
res0: Array[String] = Array(ASD-ASD, KZ)
```

And when you're calling `split()` with a string, it means that you want to have a regex. So for you to get the exact result using the double quotes, you need to do:

```
scala> "ASD-ASD.KZ".split("\\.")
res2: Array[String] = Array(ASD-ASD, KZ)
```

Where:

- First `\`  escapes the following character
- Second `\` escapes character for the dot which is a regex expression, and we want to use it as a character
- `.` - the character to split the string by